# Writing from a Array to a Cell in Google Spreadsheet (Number Format)?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I´m new to Google SpreadSheet, so forgive if this is a stupid question.

Just for practice, I´m trying to make a Sodoku Solver. I ran into a problem, while writing my code. Here it is:

In order to solve the Sodoku, I´ve made a function that checks what the possible answers for that cell are. This function cellPossibleValues(row, column) receives the cell´s row and column and return and array with the possible values for the cell. So far, so good!

When this array is equal 1, hence there is only one possible value for that cell, I tell the code to write it that value on the cell. My problem is that it doesn´t write the number, but it writes the array. (It writes "[1.0]" in the cell, instead of just "1").

Here is the code:

```
for (var row = 1; row <= 9; row++){
for(var column = 1; column <= 9; column++){

  cell = board.getCell(row, column).getValue()

  if (cell != 0){

     boardAsArray.push(cell);

 }
 else {

     boardAsArray.push(cellPossibleValues(row, column));

     if (boardAsArray[arrayPosition].length == 1) {
         board.getCell(row, column).setValue(boardAsArray[arrayPosition]);
         board.getCell(row, column).setFontColor("red");
         board.getCell(row, column).setNumberFormat("0");
     }

}

 arrayPosition = arrayPosition + 1;

 }
}
```

Here is the a image of what it is writing:

[image: Note that instead of "[7.0]" I would like it to be written just "7" in cell(2,2), for exemple]

Note that instead of "[7.0]" I would like it to be written just "7" in cell(2,2), for exemple.

I´ve tried using .setNumberFormat("0"), but it doesn´t do the trick....

What should I do?

Thank You Very Much for your Help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´ve got the solution... it was quite simple... sorry for bothering you guys...

my mistake was writing only one parameter for the array:

```
board.getCell(row, column).setValue(boardAsArray[arrayPosition]);
```

In order for this to work properly I should have written:

```
board.getCell(row, column).setValue(boardAsArray[arrayPosition][0]);
```

Well... living and learning....